Firebase authentication does not work on the apk version of the Unity app
Everything works fine in unity, authentication is going through. But when building on android, nothing comes out. I looked at who had the same problems, but it didn't really help me. I've been struggling with this for two days now
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Auth;
using System;

public class FirebaseInitScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action OnFirebaseInitialized;
    public static bool firebaseReady;

    void Start()
    {
        CheckIfReady();
    }

    public static void CheckIfReady()
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                Firebase.FirebaseApp app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
                firebaseReady = true;
                Debug.Log("Firebase is ready for use.");
                OnFirebaseInitialized?.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                firebaseReady = false;
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                  "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
            }
        });
    }
}


Logcat:
Error Unity InvalidOperationException: Don't call other Firebase functions while CheckDependencies is running.
Error Unity   at Firebase.FirebaseApp.SetCheckDependenciesThread (System.Int32 threadId) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Error Unity   at Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckDependenciesAsync () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Error Unity   at Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Error Unity   at FirebaseInitScript.CheckIfReady () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

a function to check the readiness of Firebase on the advice of stackoverflow with a similar problem
there were also other methods of elimination that did not help


    private IEnumerator DelayedInitializeFirebase()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        InitializeFirebase();
    }

in the end, it helped me

Switch ContinueWith to ContinueWithOnMainThread
Where did you see to use ContinueWith? ContinueWithOnMainThread is now best practice and if any of the Firebase SDK for Unity documentation says to use the former, I would like to know so i can change it.
